# Bootstrap Thumbnail Centering Not Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Recently I have been building a site where you can submit memes. I chose Bootstrap because that was the best option. However, I used the "thumbnail" class for my images to be in with some custom content below. Now I want to center these thumbnails, but it's just not working. I've been Googling and tried all sorts of methods but nothing have worked.

This is the partial that's showing the thumbnail (I'm using Laravel 4):

```laravel
@if($memes->count())
    @foreach($memes as $meme)
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="{{ asset($meme->image) }}">
                @include('layouts.partials.image')
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <h2 class="title">{{ $meme->title }}</h2>
                <p class="description text-muted">Submitted by {{ $meme->name }} {{ $meme->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else
    <h4 class="default-message">{{ $message }}</h4>
    {{ link_to_route('submit-a-meme', 'Submit New Meme', null, ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default']) }}
@endif
```

This is the view file that shows it:

```laravel
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    <div class="row text-center">
        <h1>THE LATEST MEMES :)</h1>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            @include('pages.home.partials.homememe', ['message' => 'Oops, no more memes  to view. Maybe you want to submit one?'])
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Everything inside the content section is wrapped in a container.

Comment: How do you want them to be centered? Horizontally or vertically, and compared to what? Currently it looks like you put all `.thumbnail` images inside a single grid column `.col-sm-6 col-md-4`. Should they get a grid like layour? Or are you thinking for of a [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) like layout?

Comment: @ckuijjer Very good questions. I want them horizontally, and I'd really like a Masonry layout. I've already included Masonry, haha :)

Comment: Cool! In that case I suggest you to just use Masonry inside a Bootstrap grid column. I think that should work.